# strange memory consumption behaviour when running PCA in python

Tags: python, performance, memory, runtime, pca

At the moment I am trying to find the reason for a specific behavior in Python.

First I want to describe my use case. The idea is a performance analysis on Python. Therefore I want to analyze the **memory usage** and **runtime** regarding the **"Principle Component Analysis"**-algorithm. For that, I use scikit-learn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

To see, how the algorithm behaves for different datasets, I generated several randomly uniform distributed datasets. The strange thing is, there is an increase in memory usage and a faster runtime regarding two datasets.

Now I want to explain, how I measure the memory-usage and runtime shortly. 
Memory measurement (package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)

- disable the garbage collection
- Use the @profile decoration to find the increments of the function
- Write the output into a log file
- Use another python program to find the increments of the log files which belong to a specific dataset
- sum up the increments - the result is the total memory allocation for the complete function
  (I tested it with enabled garbage collection, too)

Time measurement (function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

- Use "timeit.repeat()" to get a list of many runtimes of the function
- Write the list of those measurements to a CSV

After I had performed about 100 memory measurements and even more time measurements, I recognized the aforementioned behavior.
Hopefully, you can help me, find a reason for this behavior.

Here is the function, I measured:

```
@profile 
def pcaTrain(dataset):
 model = sklearn_pca.fit(dataset)
 model.variance = np.var(model.transform(dataset), axis=0, ddof=1)
 return model
```

And here are some diagrams of the memory usage and the time measurements:

[Memory measurements for dataset 4-17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dFOP.png)

[Runtime measurements for dataset 4-17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGx4p.png)

**Set up:**

- Python-version: 3.5.2
- Memory: > 100 GB

**List of datasets:**

- dset04 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (10 features x 1.000.000)
- dset05 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (12 features x 1.000.000)
- dset06 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (14 features x 1.000.000)
- dset07 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (16 features x 1.000.000)
- dset08 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (18 features x 1.000.000)
- dset09 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (20 features x 1.000.000)
- dset10 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (22 features x 1.000.000)
- dset11 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (24 features x 1.000.000)
- dset12 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (26 features x 1.000.000)
- dset13 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (28 features x 1.000.000)
- dset14 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (30 features x 1.000.000)
- dset15 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (35 features x 1.000.000)
- dset16 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (40 features x 1.000.000)
- dset17 -> 1.000.000 rows per column (45 features x 1.000.000)

Answer (score 0):

The important question is, how many of the features you are extractiong.
Since version 0.18 of Scikit-learn, the `svd_solver` flag of the PCA algorithm determines which algorithm to use. 
 The default behavior is to select the "best" choice, which is described in detail in the [official documentation which you mentioned](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html). 
Possibly, one of those selections hits your performance, depending on the number of components. Otherwise, I would suggest you mention this behavior in the official GitHub of scikit-learn, since this could be interesting to them as well.